# Emotion FOUC after upgrading to Next 13 / React 18

Tags: server-side-rendering, emotion, fouc

After upgrading our project too from Next 12/React 17 to Next 13/React 18 I am seeing FOUC (Flash of Unstyled Content) that was not present before the upgrade. Nothing within our Emotion setup has changed within the process. We use `@emotion/react` and `@emotion/styled` and are on version ^11.x.x. Has something changed with how SSR works within Emotion and React 18 that now causes the FOUC?